# Хранение планет для гравитационной задачи

Tags: структуры-данных, моделирование

Если задача хранить объекты, состоящие из четырёх чисел (x, y, z, m) и как можно быстрее искать все объекты, у которых отношение массы к квадрату расстояния до него больше какого-то числа, какую структуру лучше всего для хранения использовать? Я пока нашёл на эту тему в Википедии kd-tree, r-tree и octree, что из этого лучше использовать?

Comment: Сколько у Вас таких объектов? Квадрат расстояния до чего? До некоторой произвольной точки (x0, y0, z0)? И насколько она произвольная?

Comment: Объектов планируется около 2 миллионов, расстояния до каждого объекта. То есть нужно для каждого объекта находить те, которые на него значимо влияют, однако 4*10^12 операций проводить не хочется

Comment: Так чудес не бывает. Если объекты движутся и Вам нужно находить все расстояния то Вам нужно их тупо посчитать.

Comment: Нет, я имею ввиду, что, например, силу взаимодействия Луны и каждого спутника Юпитера считать не нужно, потому что она мала. И хотелось бы выбрать для каждого объекта те, которые на него влияют сильно, благодаря чему уменьшить количество вычислений до реалтаймового

Comment: Orbiter же как-то работает в реальном времени

Comment: Смотрите мой ответ

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой вариант, Вы при добавлении нового объекта рассчитываете данное отношение (судя по описанию, это не очень сложная вычислительная задача), и отождествляете полученный результат с ключом. Таким образом, можно будет хранить пару ключ-значение (значение - этот объект, смотря как он у Вас представлен) в ассоциативном контейнере, время доступа O(log N), в большинстве задач вполне приемлемое время поиска. Про применимость деревьев непонятно, опишите задачу детальнее.

Comment: Проблема в том, что объекты движутся друг относительно друга

Answer (score 0):

Тут у Вас не проблема хранения, а нехилая расчетная задача. И весь вопрос как бы эти расчеты оптимизировать.

Один из вариантов оптимизации. Вам нужно найти все объекты, принадлежащие некоторой сфере (центр сферы - текущий объект, радиус - Ваше граничное значение расстояния).

Впишите эту сферу в куб. Тогда для принадлежности объекта кубу нужно выполнить всего 12 линейных сравнений (или меньше, если хоть одно из них провалится). Если окажется, что объект принадлежит кубу, тогда уже проверяйте более строгое условие на принадлежность сфере.

Далее, можно единожды рассчитать для каждой пары максимально возможную силу притяжения. И тогда 90% объектов просто не будут участвовать в рассчетах